# Is the temperature of the surface of our body same as that inside the body?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, biophysics, biology

the surface of the body is always subjected to the atmospheric conditions and thus the temperature of the surface is eventually equal to the room temperature
then what does the temperature shown by the thermometre indicate?

Comment: No, the core temperature of the human body has to remain at 37 degree Celsius, and that's why your body will take blood away from your arms and legs during periods of cold. In hot weather you will sweat for the same reason, look up homeostatis. But I don't view this as a physics question.

Comment: what is the temperature measured by the thermometre then?

Comment: To measure body temperature accurately, one measures in cavities: anus, mouth, ear.

Comment: Why do you suppose that the skin surface must be in equilibrium with the environment. Steady state I can see, but unless I'm dead I think I'm still generating heat which needs to escape my body.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: but what i am asking is why do they do it there? does the measurment of temperature there give the temperature inside the body i mean the core of the body?

Comment: When one is inside (in a hospital for example), the difference between the temperature of one's forehead and core temperature is about the same for most people.

Answer (score 1):

> the surface of the body is always subjected to the atmospheric conditions and thus the temperature of the surface is eventually equal to the room temperature

A living body generates heat.

It will not cool to room temperature, but to a temperature at which the outgoing rate of heat loss is equal to the rate at which it generates heat.

> then what does the temperature shown by the thermometre indicate ?

It indicates exactly what it says : the temperature of your body at that point on it's surface.

The temperature can vary throughout your body and, of course, over the surface of your body.  When medical people take a temperature they are taking it from specific locations and using it in a way that gives reasonably consistent results for different people.

This may help : [Human Body Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_temperature)

Comment: Results are reasonably consistent in a controlled environment, like a hospital with air conditioning.

Comment: due to the biological activities energy is liberated in the body. some of this is in the form of heat. the core of the body should be at a temperature of 37 celcius and is this why the heat excess escapes from the body?